# I'm deploying Google connector for database on my server. How to find the classname of my JDBC driver?

Tags: database, connector, google-search-appliance

I'm deploying google search appliance connector for database(SQL). I'm filling the information in the GSA hostname and other required variable.

One section says to enter the full classname of JDBC driver. It has an example:

```
oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

How should I find the full classname of my JDBC driver that I installed?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the JAR file, for the drive, you can open it up (it is a zip) and then browse the directory structure.  You'll be looking for something like what you see for Oracle.

Postgres uses:

```
org.postgresql.Driver
```

MS SQL uses:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

MySQL uses:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Using that pattern, you should be able to figure it out.

Terry

Comment: Thanks, Terry. I'm using MS SQL, so I will use "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver". One more question, it also asks me for Database URL, is this the right format "jdbc:sqlserver://[serverName[\instanceName][:portNumber]][;property=value[;property=value]]"

Comment: Here is an example I used:  jdbc:sqlserver://hostname\\instance:9999;databaseName=DBName